# Should QFileSystemWatcher work with device nodes?

Tags: c++, qt, linux-device-driver, qt5, qfilesystemwatcher

Qt is new to me so I don't know all the idioms yet. I have a custom linux driver which exposes itself as `/dev/mydevice`. When something interesting happens in hardware, the driver writes some data to that file. I have tested that this works with

```
xxd -l 16 /dev/mydevice
```

and can see my data being dumped to the screen when I press a button.

Now I want a simple GUI to show me what's being dumped; `QFileSystemWatcher` seems like a good candidate since it "monitors the file system for changes to files," but it doesn't fire the `fileChanged` signal.

I'm guessing `QFileSystemWatcher` is just looking at the modification time or something like that? Since `QFile` doesn't implement the `readyRead` signal, am I down to spawning a new thread and looping on `QFile::read()`? Or implementing my own `QIODevice` that does that? What's the best way to achieve my goal?

Here is the toy example.

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileSystemWatcher>
#include <QString>

class EventTester : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    EventTester(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
        qfsw = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);

        if (!qfsw->addPath("/dev/mydevice")) {
            qDebug() << "Couldn't add watcher.";
        }
        connect(qfsw, &QFileSystemWatcher::fileChanged,
                this, &EventTester::onEvent);
    }

    QFileSystemWatcher *qfsw;

public slots:
    void onEvent(const QString &path)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(path);
        qDebug() << "We got a special event!";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    EventTester e();

    return a.exec();
}
```

qfswtestcon.pro:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = qfswtestcon
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Comment: Are you running your program by sudo privileges?

Comment: @Nejat: It's running on an embedded system which currently only has the root user defined, so I'm running this as root, yes.